# Cancel an async operation after the form has loaded?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have different classes (implementing an interface) where one method is to perform an async databases search:

```
public async void SearchAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {Find(); }, ct);
}

private void Find()
{
    //do db search here...
}
```

When forms are opened, a background async search is performed to speed up user entry, so what I do is:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    try
    {
        //Get list of items that will perform async search...
        //var results = ...

        //Do an async search
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    item.SearchAsync(cts.Token);
                }
            }, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { }
}
```

Just in case the user closes the form whilst and tasks are still performing, I do:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

First of all, is the above the correct way to perform async operations?

Secondly, when I close the form whilst the tasks are still not completed, the code never reaches the OperationCancelException. Could it be that the above implementation is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of this to note. First, you're using the ["async over sync"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) anti-pattern, which should be strongly avoided. You're also passing a `CancellationToken` but actually never monitoring on it. If your method is synchronous, you can't really monitor it while executing, the best you can do is monitor the `CancellationToken` before you execute each iteration of `Search`:

```
public void Search()
{
    Find();
}

protected override async void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnShown(e);

   try
   {
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           foreach (var item in results)
           {
               cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               item.Search();
           }
       }, cts.Token);
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException)
   { }
}
```

And then you cancel:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```